# running php code in files ending in asp

Tags: php, asp.net, wordpress, .htaccess

A  non-technical owner of an authority site with 1000s of asp/aspx pages decided to rebuild the site using WordPress on a new cPanel server.  The original site was on a windows server and built with ASP.net.  The problem is that they now had lots of dead external links going to *.asp and *.aspx pages that no longer existed.

I can get the static, mostly html content from the old site and wrap a php template derived from the WordPress template around it
I've added the following lines to .htaccess file so that asp and aspx files should be able to use php code, but this is not working.

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .asp
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .aspx
```

Any suggestions about getting php code to execute with files ending in .asp/.aspx on a linux host?

Comment: What exactly happens when you go to **foo.asp** ?

Comment: /* I see */<?php include "template-before.shtml" ;?>
content goes here
<?php include "template-after.shtml" ;?> /* in other words, the php code does not execute */

Comment: if I rename foo.asp to foo.php then the php code in foo.php does execute

Answer (score 1):

You can also set mime type handler using a RewriteRule

Try :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^.+\.aspx?$ - [H=application/x-httpd-php5]
```

x is optional in the pattern above ,so it matches both **.asp** or **.aspx** .